Conditional and unconditional mean in GARCH(1,1) model
I have a time series which is stationary through adf.test in R. This means the conditional and unconditional mean of the time series should be the same. When I run a constant mean GARCH(1,1) model using rugarch, the mu parameter is not the same as the mean() of the time series. This is strange as these should be the same because of the stationarity. Any ideas on why this might be the case? (Think of df as synthetic stationary time series)
spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)),
                   mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0)))
garch_model <- ugarchfit(spec, data = df)

